# Is there a valid JCR sql2 statement for DeleteAll method?

Tags: jcr, jcr-sql2

I followed the statement `DELETE [address : Address]` where `Address` is one of the entities. Please help in this regard with possible examples on how to implement `DeleteAll` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard JCR-SQL2 query language defined in the [JCR 2.0 (JSR-283) specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=283) is *read only*, and has no delete (or update or create) functionality.